# WCF: Make all calls wait when one specific interface is being called

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, concurrency

I have a WCF service with quite a few interfaces which only read data. There is however one interface that reloads data from the database and reinitialises some dictionaries. While this interface "Reload" is running I effectively want all other calls to be put "on hold" as they would read data of an unknown state (as I am using per-call)

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyObject
{
    [OperationContract] 
    string Reload();
    [OperationContract]
    string Read1();
    [OperationContract]
    string Read2();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
class MyObject : IMyObject
{
    public string Reload() { //Takes 5-10secs, called twice a day  }
    public string Read1() {  //Wait for Reload() to finish if it's running}
    public string Read2() {  //Wait for Reload() to finish if it's running} 
}
```

Is this possible in WCF? Or is there a best practise way around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you play with the [ConcurrencyMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode.aspx) and set it to single you can achieve what you want.

Having said that, I had achieved what you want having a flag on my services. If you set a static flag other calls can check for that flag and do what ever you want them to do

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you to:

1. Change InstanceContextMode.PerCall to InstanceContextMode.Single
2. Then add ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple (will allow more than 1 execution in a time)
3. In your MyObject implementation manually deal with concurrency. Use simple `lock` or advanced mechanics, like [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx).

Implementation with lock is as follows:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
class MyObject: IMyObject
{
    private readonly object lockObject = new object();
    public string Reload()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            // Reload stuff
        }
    }
    public string Read1()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            // Read1 stuff
        }
    }

    public string Read2()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            // Read2 stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Drawbacks, that it won't allow you to call simultaneously Read1 and Read2. If you need this functionality, use [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) instead of lock.